# Google App Script .getEvents issue - How to retrieve events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to do some basic stuff with GAS. I would like to retrieve the events from a specific calendar but every time the returned value is 0 (which is impossible since my calendar is full of events).

I checked the settings in GAS Editor and my calendar. All timeZones are set on GMT+01.

```
function SearchEventForFirstCall() {

 var now = new Date();
 Logger.log('NOW: ' + now);
 var nowPlusOneMonth = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth()+1));
 Logger.log('DATE PLUS 1 MONTH: ' + nowPlusOneMonth);

 var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('123456789@group.calendar.google.com');
 Logger.log('CALENDAR: ' + calendar);
 var events = calendar.getEvents(now,nowPlusOneMonth);
 Logger.log('EVENTS: ' + events.length);

}
```

Here's the transcript:

```
1[19-11-28 20:43:54:617 CET] Starting execution
2[19-11-28 20:43:54:706 CET] Logger.log([NOW : Thu Nov 28 2019 20:43:54 GMT+0100 (CET), []]) [0 seconds]
3[19-11-28 20:43:54:706 CET] Logger.log([DATE PLUS 1 MONTH : Sat Dec 28 2019 20:43:54 GMT+0100 (CET), []]) [0 seconds]
4[19-11-28 20:43:54:850 CET] CalendarApp.getCalendarById([123456789@group.calendar.google.com]) [0.142 seconds]
5[19-11-28 20:43:54:850 CET] Logger.log([CALENDAR : Calendar, []]) [0 seconds]
6[19-11-28 20:43:55:094 CET] CalendarApp.Calendar.getEvents([Sat Dec 28 11:43:54 PST 2019, Sat Dec 28 11:43:54 PST 2019]) [0.242 seconds]
7[19-11-28 20:43:55:095 CET] Logger.log([Events: 0, []]) [0 seconds]
8[19-11-28 20:43:55:097 CET] Execution succeeded [0.391 seconds total runtime]
```

Why is there two identical PST dates (6th line in the transcript)?

Using this solve the problem.

```
 var now = new Date('2019-11-28');
 var nowPlusOneMonth = new Date('2019-12-28');
```

Date format seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly creating the end date. If you were to log the `now` date after you have constructed the `nowPlusOneMonth` you would see that both are the same. So your range is just a few milliseconds.

I would change the creation of `nowPlusOneMonth` like so:

```js
function SearchEventForFirstCall() {

 var now = new Date();
 var nowPlusOneMonth = new Date(); // Create a date as of now
 nowPlusOneMonth.setMonth(nowPlusOneMonth.getMonth() +1 ); // Sum one month
 Logger.log('NOW: ' + now); // Also I changed the log after the creation of the dates
 Logger.log('DATE PLUS 1 MONTH: ' + nowPlusOneMonth);

 var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('primary');
 Logger.log('CALENDAR: ' + calendar);
 var events = calendar.getEvents(now,nowPlusOneMonth);
 Logger.log('EVENTS: ' + events.length);

}
```

If you still need help I would suggest looking at the documentation of the [`getEvents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar.html#geteventsstarttime,-endtime) method. There is an example similar at what you are trying to achieve (two hour ahead instead of one month).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I also found a workaround with `month = now.getMonth()+1;`. I did it for the date and year and finally got `nowPlusOneMonth = new Date(year,month,date);`